# TextMate + R bundle: disable online help when opening parentheses

Tags: macos, mac, textmate, r

Using TextMate with the R bundle, whenever I open a new bracket or parenthesis, the program pauses for a few seconds while the R bundle loads up a online help tooltip for the function that I've opened the bracket for. This happens for each bracket, adding a large number of 2-3 second pauses in my workflow. It's really hampering my productivity.

I was wondering if there was a way to disable that online help tooltip feature of the R bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foolish. In my rage I didn't think to check the help file for the R.tmbundle. It turns out that it's clearly labelled in section 2.9:

> *Hint* This functionality can be switched off by deactivating the bound key equivalent within in the Bundle Editor.